# How do I get taxonomy terms by ID in a specific order

Tags: php, taxonomy, terms

How do I get taxonomy terms by ID in a specific order. Below is my code and I thought if I passed `get_terms` the arguments to with ID and post_in but I am not seeing the results I thought I should.

```
$args_terms = array(
                'post_in' => array(47, 48, 49, 46 , 50, 5),
                'orderby' => 'post_in',
                'parent' => '0'
            );

$custom_post_type = 'menu-food';
$taxonomy = 'menu-food-categories';
$taxonomy_terms = get_terms( $taxonomy, $args_terms);
```

Comment: Can you say why you are using `post_in` in `$args_terms`? I do not think this can be passed as an argument.

Comment: I am not sure how else to order the ID's so the terms are returned in that order. I am open to suggestions. lol

Comment: Can you specify the term ordering you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 4):

[`get_terms` does not support a `post__in` argument](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms#Parameters) and I don't see any other argument that will let you force an order. You can, however, accomplish this with one fof at least two filters:

```
function gto_forced_order($orderby) {
  $orderby = "FIELD(t.term_id,5,1,4)";
  return $orderby;
}
add_filter('get_terms_orderby','gto_forced_order');

$terms = get_terms('category');
var_dump($terms);
```

Or...

```
function gto_forced_order($pieces) {
  $pieces['orderby'] = "ORDER BY FIELD(t.term_id,5,1,4)";
  return $pieces;
}
add_filter('terms_clauses','gto_forced_order');
```

That `5,1,4` are the term IDs. The query will sort in whatever is given there.

Those filters will both work globally, changing every call to `get_terms`, but by using the other arguments the filters offer you can control where the filter runs.

```
function gto_forced_order($pieces,$taxonomies,$args) {
  if (in_array('category',$taxonomies)) {
    $pieces['orderby'] = "ORDER BY FIELD(t.term_id,5,1,4)";
  }
  return $pieces;
}
add_filter('terms_clauses','gto_forced_order',1,3);
```

If you add `var_dump($pieces,$taxonomies,$args)` to the top of that callback you can see what you have to work with (though it will make a mess-- debugging only).

It is similar with `get_terms_orderby` but the [parameters are a bit different](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8/src/wp-includes/taxonomy.php#L1340).

Comment: I am going to test this now. What are the 1,3 in the add filter? Thanks for your help.

Comment: So that worked but I have a few questions. Will that change every call to get_terms used on the site? Can i have this not happen? And why does get_terms change get_terms_orderby? Shouldn't they be the same name. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks